# Expressão regular não valida senha quando digito apenas números

Tags: c#, regex

Estou usando essa expressão regular para validar minha senha, a senha deve ter apenas letras e números, deve ter pelo menos uma letra e um número. (Mínimo 8 caracteres).

Estou usando essa expressão:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[A-Za-z0-9]*\d+[A-Za-z0-9]*$")]
```

Quando digito `qwertyu1` ela valida corretamente.

O erro está quando digito `12345678` ela valida sem precisar digitar uma letra.

Comment: Sim, é o que sua RegEx pede. Ela não obriga nenhuma letra. Você pos como opcionais (*) os dois grupos com letra dentro, e obrigatório (+) apenas dígitos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Primeiro vamos analisar sua regex e entender porque ela não funciona:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]*\d+[A-Za-z0-9]*$
```

Os marcadores `^` e `$` indicam, respectivamente, o início e fim da string.

Em seguida, temos `[A-Za-z0-9]*`. Os colchetes definem uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), que basicamente significa "pegue qualquer coisa que esteja nos colchetes". Portanto `[A-Za-z0-9]` significa "qualquer caractere que seja letra maiúscula (`A-Z`), **ou** letra minúscula (`a-z`) **ou** um dígito (`0-9`)".

Já o quantificador `*` significa "zero ou mais ocorrências". Portanto o trecho `[A-Za-z0-9]*` significa "zero ou mais ocorrências de letras ou números". Ou seja, se tiver alguma letra (ou só letras), serve. Se tiver algum número (ou somente números), também serve. E se não tiver nada, também serve (já que o `*` indica "**zero** ou mais ocorrências").

Depois temos `\d+`. O `\d` é um [atalho para `[0-9]`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) - mas dependendo da linguagem/engine/configuração usada, o `\d` também pode corresponder a outros dígitos (como por exemplo os caracteres `٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩`), conforme explicado [nesta resposta](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/414230). Se quer garantir que sua regex aceitará somente os dígitos ASCII (de `0` a `9`), use `[0-9]`.

Já o `+` indica "uma ou mais ocorrências", portanto `\d+` significa "uma ou mais ocorrências de dígitos". Repare que pode ser qualquer quantidade maior ou igual 1, portanto isso não serve para o seu caso, que precisa ter pelo menos 8 caracteres.

E para finalizar, temos novamente `[A-Za-z0-9]*`, que significa "zero ou mais ocorrências de letras ou números".

Ou seja, esta regex não obriga que tenha pelo menos uma letra, pois ela define que zero ou mais ocorrências de letras ou números são aceitas. Além disso, os quantificadores `*` e `+` não obrigam a ter pelo menos 8 caracteres (já que 1 caractere já seria suficiente). A única coisa que esta regex obriga é que tenha pelo menos um dígito (`\d+`).

---

### Solução

Uma maneira de resolver seria esta regex:

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}$
```

Os marcadores `^` e `$` indicam, respectivamente, o início e fim da string. Com isso, garantimos que a string inteira contém somente o que está na regex.

Em seguida temos `(?=.*[0-9])`. Os parênteses com ponto de interrogação e igual `(?=)` [significam que este trecho é um *lookahead*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Basicamente, é uma forma de fazer a regex "olhar o que tem na frente" e ver se bate com a expressão dentro dos parênteses. Dentro do *lookahead* temos `.*[0-9]`, que significa "zero ou mais ocorrências de qualquer caractere (`.*`) seguido de um dígito (`[0-9]`)". Ou seja, é uma regex que verifica se tem um dígito na string.

O "truque" é que o *lookahead* verifica se há um dígito mas depois "volta para onde estava" (no caso, o início da string) e verifica o restante da expressão. Ou seja, `(?=.*[0-9])` verifica se há algum dígito e em seguida volta ao início da string e continua avaliando o restante da regex.

Em seguida temos outro *lookahead*: `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])`. Ele é parecido com o anterior, só que agora verifica se há alguma letra, e depois volta para a posição onde estava (no caso, o início da string) e continua avaliando o restante da regex.

Em seguida temos `[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}`. O `[a-zA-Z0-9]` significa "letras ou números", e o quantificador `{8,}` significa "8 ou mais ocorrências".

Ou seja:

- o primeiro *lookahead* (`(?=.*[0-9])`) garante que há pelo menos um dígito na string
- o segundo *lookahead* (`(?=.*[a-zA-Z])`) garante que há pelo menos uma letra na string
- o restante (`[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}`) garante que há pelo menos 8 caracteres na string (e que todos os caracteres são letras ou números)

Se quiser limitar também o tamanho máximo, pode colocar depois da vírgula. Por exemplo, `{8,20}` limitaria a string a ter de 8 a 20 caracteres.

Você pode ver esta regex funcionando [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/cY1k1g/1).

Comment: Obrigado pela solução e pela explicação de como funciona a expressão regular.