# Regex caracteres especiais obrigatório

Tags: java, android, regex

Preciso criar um regex para validar senha.

Ela deverá conter no mínimo 8 caracteres, dos quais deve possuir no mínimo 1 letra, 1 número e 1 caractere especial.

Comment: Marcelo, acredito que esse tipo de pergunta já tenha sido respondida dezenas de vezes e você pode encontrar a resposta no Google. Veja esse [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605150/regex-for-password-must-contain-at-least-eight-characters-at-least-one-number-a)

Comment: Leitura obrigatória para quem é da área: https://xkcd.com/936/ ; se deseja usar esse esquema de segurança, saiba que ele é falido por definição. O único jeito de garantir que a entropia da senha a torne forte contra ataques brutos é com o seu tamanho. A força para quebrar uma senha de `d` dígitos sobre um alfabeto de `A` caracteres distintos é `O(A**d)`; daí, se você apenas subir o `A`, o quanto que você ganha de complexidade é minguante perante o aumento na quantidade de dígitos

Comment: Não é exatamente o que vc quer (é quase) mas já dá pra ter uma ideia: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/337981/112052 - e sobre caracteres especiais: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/342737/112052

Comment: o que você considera um caractere especial amigo? poderia listar alguns exemplos?

Comment: Obrigado pessoal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regex Usada**

Essa regex faz a validação, [você pode testa-la aqui](https://regex101.com/r/Kgf1Q0/1/):

```
(?=.*[}{,.^?~=+\-_\/*\-+.\|])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{8,}
```

Lembrando que você deve usar duplo escape aonde tem o caractere `\`, então no código Java todos as barras invertidas devem ser duplas, ficando `\\`.

---

**Aplicação no código Java**

No código Java você pode fazer a validação com `String.matches`, do jeito que mostrei abaixo:

```
public class JavaFiddle
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     System.out.println("A{123456".matches("(?=.*[}{,.^?~=+\\-_\\/*\\-+.\\|])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{8,}")); //exemplo que passa
     System.out.println("ASD1ASDA".matches("(?=.*[}{,.^?~=+\\-_\\/*\\-+.\\|])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{8,}")); //exemplo que nao passa (falta caractere especial)
     System.out.println("ASDAS^^?".matches("(?=.*[}{,.^?~=+\\-_\\/*\\-+.\\|])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{8,}")); //exemplo que nao passa (falta numero)
     System.out.println("123^8542".matches("(?=.*[}{,.^?~=+\\-_\\/*\\-+.\\|])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{8,}")); //exemplo que nao passa (falta letra)
     System.out.println("WWEA^^1".matches("(?=.*[}{,.^?~=+\\-_\\/*\\-+.\\|])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{8,}")); //exemplo que nao passa (nao tem minimo de 8 caracteres)
   }
}
```

Este código exibe `true` no console quando for um padrão válido, e `false` para padrões inválidos.
Você pode testar esse código no [JavaFiddle](https://javafiddle.leaningtech.com/) como eu fiz também, só copiar e colar o código dessa resposta.

OBS: Como não foi especificado quais seriam os caracteres especiais eu utilizei como válidos os seguintes caracteres (`,.^?~=+-_/*\+`)
Você pode alterar os caracteres que entram como caracteres especiais nessa parte da regex: 
`(?=.*[}{,.^?~=+\-_\/*\-+.\|])`, só não retire a parte `(?=` ... `)`, pois isso sinaliza um *positive lookahead*, que é necessário para validar que existe pelo menos um dos caracteres sinalizados no grupo antes de iniciar a captura.

---

**Explicação da Regex**

- `(?=.*`...`)` - É um *positive lookahead* que irá garantir que o grupo de caracteres a seguir DEVE estar na string para que ela seja validada.
- `[}{,.^?~=+\-_\/*\-+.\|]` - É o *set* que define quais caracteres podem ser capturados pelo *positive lookahead*.
- `(?=.*`...`)` - É um *positive lookahead* que irá garantir que o grupo de caracteres a seguir DEVE estar na string para que ela seja validada.
- `[a-zA-Z]` - É o set que caracteriza qualquer caractere de letra sendo maiúscula ou minúscula.
- `(?=.*`...`)` - É um *positive lookahead* que irá garantir que o grupo de caracteres a seguir DEVE estar na string para que ela seja validada.
- `[0-9]` - É o set que caracteriza qualquer número entre 0 e 9.
- `.{8,}` - Após essas validações, será capturado uma sequencia de qualquer caractere que não contenha quebra de linhas(sinalizado pelo `.`).
   E que seja de comprimento mínimo de 8 caracteres (sinalizado pelo `{8,}`), sem limite máximo (caso queira definir um limite você pode colocar o número máximo de caractere após a `,`).

EDITADO
Obrigado ao usuário [@hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112052/hkotsubo) por me avisar do meu erro

Comment: Na verdade o `.` aceita espaços sim, [veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/8rtOcc/1/). E aceita qualquer outro caractere que não foi especificado anteriormente: https://regex101.com/r/8rtOcc/2/ (não que isso seja problema, já que a pergunta não deixa claro o que é pra ter ou não)

Comment: @hkotsubo aí você me pegou kkk, eu quis dizer quebra de linha, erro meu. Vou corrigir.

Comment: É, por padrão o `.` não considera quebras de linha. Mas - por curiosidade - é possível fazer com que considere, usando a opção `DOTALL`: https://ideone.com/rAxncr

Comment: Top muito obrigado!

Comment: @Marcelo considere marcar a resposta como correta, se ela te respondeu a duvida inicial

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde.

Estou usando o FluentValidation e fiz algumas validações para senha hoje. Vê se isso te ajuda (Caso tive alguma dúvida do código me fale):

```
using FluentValidation;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace SaleTheaterTickets.Models.ViewModelValidators
{
    public class RegisterViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<RegisterViewModel>
    {
        public RegisterViewModelValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.Email)
                .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Informe o e-mail")
                .EmailAddress().WithMessage("Digite um e-mail válido (ana@gmail.com)");
            RuleFor(x => x.Password)
                .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Informe a senha")
                .Length(6, 20).WithMessage("Senha deve ter no mínimo 6 e no máximo 20 caractéres")
                .Must(RequireDigit).WithMessage("Senha deve ter pelo menos 1 número")
                .Must(RequiredLowerCase).WithMessage("Senha deve ter pelo menos 1 caracter minúsculo")
                .Must(RequireUppercase).WithMessage("Senha deve ter pelo menos 1 caracter maiúsculo")
                .Must(RequireNonAlphanumeric).WithMessage("Digite pelo menos 1 caracter especial (@ ! & * ...)");
            RuleFor(x => x.ConfirmPassword)
                .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Confirme a senha")
                .Equal(x => x.Password).WithMessage("Senhas não conferem");
        }

        private bool RequireDigit(string password)
        {
            if (password.Any(x => char.IsDigit(x)))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private bool RequiredLowerCase(string password)
        {
            if (password.Any(x => char.IsLower(x)))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private bool RequireUppercase(string password)
        {
            if (password.Any(x => char.IsUpper(x)))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private bool RequireNonAlphanumeric(string password)
        {
            //if (password.Any(x => char.IsSymbol(x)))
            //{
            //    return true;
            //}
            //return false;

            if (Regex.IsMatch(password, "(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])"))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

OBS: Os métodos estão inglês, mas eles servem para o seguinte:

RequireDigit - pelo menos 1 número na senha
RequiredLowerCase - pelo menos 1 letra minúscula na senha
RequireUppercase - pelo menos 1 letra maiúscula na senha
RequireNonAlphanumeric - pelo menos um caractere especial na senha

OBS: O Asp.Net Core Identity já faz essas verificações, porém eu não estava conseguindo traduzir as mensagens que vinham como padrão, então peguei e criei cada validação por conta própria (seguindo as validações que vi na documentação que o Identity faz para senha) para poder gerar minhas frases em português.

Espero que te ajude de alguma forma!