# Expressão Regular para validar senha - PHP

Tags: php, regex

Pesquisei aqui no SO e tbm no Google, mas não encontrei algo que agisse como eu gostaria, também não sou bom com expressões regulares, confesso que tenho certa dificuldade e gostaria de fazer uma validação de senha em `PHP` que:

- Tenha pelo menos 8 caracteres (isso eu verifico usando strlen());
- Possua pelo menos 1 número;
- Possua pelo menos 1 letra maiúscula;
- Possua pelo menos 1 letra minúscula;
- Possua pelo menos 1 caractere especial;

Se alguém puder me dar uma luz, ficarei grato.

Comment: Dá pra se basear nessa: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/337924/112052

Comment: Se o _encoding_ for UTF8 talvez seja melhor usar `mb_strlen()` senão um caractere acentuado pode contar como mais de 1 byte.

Comment: @hkotsubo muito obrigado pela base, vai me ajudar mto sim, só dar uma implementada!

Comment: @fernandosavio muito obrigado por lembrar desse detalhe que tbm passou despercebido!
Vcs são demais!

Comment: assim que eu deixar 100% vou postar aqui a resposta

Comment: Ah, e "caracteres especiais" é uma definição meio "vaga", já que cada um define de um jeito (qual a lista exata de caracteres especiais? Depende, cada um implementa de um jeito) Então vc deve definir quais vai aceitar e quais não vai, dá uma lida aqui tb: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/342737/112052

Comment: [correct horse battery staple](https://xkcd.com/936/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Já tem um bom tempo, mas vai aqui uma possibilidade de validar apenas com um regex puro:

```
/(?!\s)(?=.*?[a-z]{1,})(?=.*?[A-Z]{1,})(?=.*?\d{1,}).*(?=.?[^a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})?.([^\s]){8,}/g
```

No último parênteses, dentro do colchete, você pode excluir todos os caracteres que quiser, por exemplo, se quiser remover aspas:

```
([^\s'"`])
```

Testando:

[image: regexr]

**Explicando um pouco:**

Quando você quer mais de uma regra no regex, onde precise passar por todas, você utiliza `(?=seu_regex)` (seria similar ao `&&` em linguagens de programação).

Como nesse caso, não importa a ordem do que foi digitado, desde que tenha todos os caracteres, então pra cada regra desejada, você utiliza: `.*?`, algo como "independente de quantos ou que vem antes, valide minha regra". Logo:

```
(?=.*?seu_regex)
```

Quando você precisa quantificar suas regras, é só utilizar `{n}` para uma quantidade exata, ou {n,} para "a partir de". Então, se quisesse obrigar no mínimo quatro letras minúsculas, `{4,}`. Seguindo o caso da sua pergunta:

```
(?=.*?seu_regex{1,})
```