# Regex para senha forte

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, npm

Estou querendo criar uma expressão que crie uma senha com:

- 8 caracteres no mínimo
- 1 Letra Maiúscula no mínimo
- 1 Número no mínimo
- 1 Símbolo no mínimo: `$*&@#`
- Se der, também não permitir sequência igual (`aa`, `bb`, `44`, etc)

Já achei vários tutoriais mas até agora nenhum deu certo.

Alguem saberia me ajudar com esta expressão?

Estou usando o módulo [randexp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/randexp) para gerar a senha.

Comment: Vc pode se basear [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/342605/112052) e [nessa outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/337924/112052) também

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sua expressão deveria ficar assim:

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[$*&@#])[0-9a-zA-Z$*&@#]{8,}$/
```

Explicando em mais detalhes:

```
/^
  (?=.*\d)              // deve conter ao menos um dígito
  (?=.*[a-z])           // deve conter ao menos uma letra minúscula
  (?=.*[A-Z])           // deve conter ao menos uma letra maiúscula
  (?=.*[$*&@#])         // deve conter ao menos um caractere especial
  [0-9a-zA-Z$*&@#]{8,}  // deve conter ao menos 8 dos caracteres mencionados
$/
```

Comment: Vlw, era isso que eu queria rs

Answer (score 6):

A [resposta do MonneratRJ](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/373586/112052) já resolve a maior parte do que você precisa. Só gostaria de acrescentar uma regex para verificar a última condição (não permitir dois ou mais caracteres seguidos iguais, como `aa`, `bb`), já que isso não estava coberto nos links [que sugeri nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/373574/regex-para-senha-forte/373586#comment742587_373574):

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[$*&@#])(?:([0-9a-zA-Z$*&@#])(?!\1)){8,}$
```

O trecho que faz a verificação é `(?:([0-9a-zA-Z$*&@#])(?!\1))`. Explicando de dentro para fora:

- `([0-9a-zA-Z$*&@#])`: é uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) contendo números, letras e os caracteres especiais que você está considerando. Eles estão dentro de parênteses para formar um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)
- `(?!\1)`: é um [*lookahead* negativo](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), que verifica se algo não existe à frente. No caso, `\1` significa "o trecho que foi capturado pelo primeiro grupo de captura".

Como o primeiro grupo de captura é um caractere que pode ser número, letra ou `$*&@#`, o *lookahead* negativo verifica se esse mesmo caractere não está à frente. Se estiver (ou seja, se o mesmo caractere aparece repetido duas vezes seguidas), a regex falha.

Por fim, eu coloco tudo isso dentro de `(?:` e `)`, pois isso forma um [grupo de não-captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap) (eu não quero que esse trecho todo interfira no `\1`, então ele não deve ser um grupo de captura), e depois eu coloco o `{8,}` para que tenha no mínimo 8 caracteres.

O "truque" do *lookahead* é que ele só verifica o que está (ou o que não está) à frente, e em seguida volta para onde estava e continua avaliando o restante da regex. Por isso o *lookahead* negativo não interfere na contagem de caracteres: ele só vê se o próximo é o mesmo (graças à referência `\1`), e se não for, volta para onde estava e continua verificando a regex (no caso, se tem pelo menos 8 caracteres dentre os que foram especificados).

Testando:

```js
let r = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[$*&@#])(?:([0-9a-zA-Z$*&@#])(?!\1)){8,}$/;

console.log(r.test('a12B@cde')); // true
console.log(r.test('a12B@cce')); // false
console.log(r.test('a22B@cde')); // false
console.log(r.test('a12@@cde')); // false
console.log(r.test('a12B@cCe')); // true
```

Se quiser rejeitar também sequências como `aA`, basta usar a opção `i` na regex:

```js
let r = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[$*&@#])(?:([0-9a-zA-Z$*&@#])(?!\1)){8,}$/i;

console.log(r.test('a12B@cde')); // true
console.log(r.test('a12B@cce')); // false
console.log(r.test('a22B@cde')); // false
console.log(r.test('a12@@cde')); // false
console.log(r.test('a12B@cCe')); // false
```

Comment: Muito obrigado complementou muito

Comment: Eu queria entender de onde vocês tiram essas expressões cara, eu não entendo nada

Comment: @RichardWillian Sim, regex é complicado e eu demorei **muito** pra aprender. Dois sites que eu gosto bastante e tem tutoriais interessantes são [esse](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) e [esse](https://www.rexegg.com). E livros, eu recomendo [esse](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do) e [esse](https://www.amazon.com/Regular-Expressions-Cookbook-Solutions-Programming/dp/1449319432) (mas aí já são mais avançados, só recomendo ler se depois de dominar o básico). E aqui no site, na tag [tag:regex] você tb pode procurar por problemas específicos, tem bastante coisa

Comment: Caraca muito bacana, vou tentar aprender, porque é a gente ta sempre usando cara e eu sempre preciso vir na net procurar uma pronta. Muito obrigado em.