# Regex para pegar sequencia de letras iguais

Tags: typescript, regex

Estou realizando um validação de senha com a determinada REGEX

```js
const regex = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[$*&@#])(?:([0-9a-zA-Z$*&@#])(?!\1)){8,}$/i
```

E dentro dela realizo diversas verificações e uma deles em especifico é sobre proibir sequencias de letras (aa, Aa, aA) maiusculas e minusculas.

e eu tenho funções que vão atualizando conforme o usuario vai digitando. Eles mostram um CHECK ou um X, indicando que a senha esta no padrao ou nao

```js
const hasUpper = (str: string) => /[A-Z]/.test(str)
const hasNumber = (str: string) => /[0-9]/.test(str)
const hasEspecial = (str: string) => /[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g.test(str)

hasUpper verifica se tem Maiusculas
hasNumber verifica se tem numeros
hasEspecial verifica se tem caracteres especiais
```

e falta uma função só para verificar se tem sequencias de letras.

Link da REGEX --> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/373601/308839

Comment: Os links indicados acima no box azul mostram como fazer, basta adaptar pro seu caso. Ver também [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8686/112052) (na seção sobre senhas, tem vários links que podem ajudar). Se bem que, para verificações mais complexas, é mais simples fazer um loop pelos caracteres da senha e ir verificando um a um (por exemplo, comparando com o caractere anterior para verificar sequências).

Comment: [Veja aqui](https://tinyurl.com/3unn9p4z) um exemplo simples sem regex (que acho mais fácil de entender e manter, inclusive pra adicionar novas regras)